# SAS Set two unequal data sets together horizontally, copy down smaller fille

Tags: sas, append, datastep

Have two datasets, one one row, the other 100 rows.  I want to set them together horizontally (not merge) and copy down the one row to all 100 rows.

Right now I make a loop to copy down the rows of the smaller dataset, however its not very efficient and filling up my log.  Looking for a cleaner way.

```
data sample_ds1;
infile datalines dlm=',';
input country $ maternal_2004 maternal_2005;
datalines;
MS,5,0
Mi,3,0
Mu,4,0
My,5,0
Mr,6,0
Mw,7,0
Mj,8,0
;

data sample_ds12temp;
infile datalines dlm=',';
input MEAN;
datalines;
3.5
;

data sample_ds12;
  set sample_ds12temp;
  run;

  do i=1 to 10;
  proc append base=sample_ds12 data=sample_ds12temp; run;
   end;

data together;
set sample_ds1;
set sample_ds1;
run;
```

Comment: Do you want to add the constant from the single observation dataset to all observations in your other dataset?

Comment: What does "not merge" mean?  Set together horizontally is merge, as far as SAS terminology goes: merge [horizontal] or append [vertical].  If you mean you don't want to merge by a variable, that's fine.

Comment: Providing an example of what the output dataset would look like would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correct then this should do the trick.

```
data A;
infile datalines dlm=',';
input country $ maternal_2004 maternal_2005;
datalines;
MS,5,0
Mi,3,0
Mu,4,0
My,5,0
Mr,6,0
Mw,7,0
Mj,8,0
;

data B;
infile datalines dlm=',';
input MEAN;
datalines;
3.5
;

data test;
if _n_=1 then set B;
set A;
run;
```

Comment: This is the right approach.  However, you should add some explanation for why it works - code-only answers are not good answers.